# Visualize image from SQL database

Tags: java, sql, image, android-studio

I'm using android studio to create an app. The idea is to load a image from a SQL database. But I'm having difficulties with it. I'm able to load the text parts which are in the database, but I'm unable to visualize the image. I also want to visualize the text and picture with the same button click.
I'm hosting my SQL server myself, Datatypes of my database are

ID = int

Name = char(10)

Filepath = char(150)

Picture = image

Down here you see my MainActivity.java.
I've tried many ways already to visualize it already, but can't seem to find it working. I've also changed the getByte to getBlob but this doesn't make a difference.

```
package com.allcodingtutorials.sqlconnection;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Rnumber;
    Button update;
    TextView name, path;
    ImageView picture;

    Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Rnumber = findViewById(R.id.textLoadData);
        update  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetData);
        name  = findViewById(R.id.Viewtext);
        path = findViewById(R.id.Viewtextpath);
        picture = findViewById(R.id.Viewimage);



        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String loadData = Rnumber.getText().toString();
                ConSQL con = new ConSQL();
                connection = con.conclass();
                if(con !=null){
                    try {
                        String sqlstatement="Select * From DatabasePictures where ID='"+ loadData +"'";
                        Statement smt = connection.createStatement();
                        ResultSet set = smt.executeQuery(sqlstatement);
                        while (set.next()){
                            name.setText(set.getString(2));
                            path.setText(set.getString(3));
                            picture.setImageBitmap(set.getByte(4));

                        }
                        //if(set.next()){
                        //    byte[] image = set.getByte(4);
                        //    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0, image.length);
                        //   picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        //}
                        connection.close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Does anyone have some advice or tips how to solve this.

Comment: Are you hosting the image on a server that is publicly available? For example, can you surf to it with an ip address (which is not localhost / 127.0.0.1)? Or do you want to access a file that is on C:\...\cat.jpg? In the last case, that is not possible since your android device that you are emulating / have has no access to that filelocation.

Comment: I'm hosting the server which is not an localhost. So, I can host my server on my laptop and access the data from my android device/mobilephone. I've also tried the file path, but found out that's not possible

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this is a **Java** question and has nothing to do with **JavaScript**. The two have very little in common except the name and a very vaguely similiar syntax.